# Create user page at subdomain

Tags: python, mod-rewrite, apache2, plone, zope

How to implement automatic page creation on a subdomain when a new user registers on the site?

(Working in Python on the Plone CMS and Zope web app server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a wildcard entry on your domain, i.e. *.example.com and use some of apache's rewrite magic to redirect this to the correct part of your site. This is already discussed elsewhere on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain)