# Simple .htaccess subdomain rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there is a lot of questions on here about this... but right now I feel like a deer stunned by oncoming headlights... I just don't know where to start and which option to choose.

My requirements are simple.

User goes to http://application.domain.com or http://www.application.domain.com and the real location of these files is http://www.domain.com/application

**Obviously this needs to be done using wildcards so that any domain (even if it doesn't exist) triggers the rewrite.**

I hope this makes sense to someone

**EDIT:
I should also mention I have added the wildcard A record to my DNS entries in Cpanel *.domain.com**

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question onto serverfault.com and icyrock solved it. Incase anyone else is wondering the answer given is here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite/203804#203804

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way in .htaccess would be to put the following in an htaccess file as high up in the hierarchy as possible.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.application\.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^application\.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/application [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. How can I modify this so it uses wildcards so I dont have to create a new htaccess entry for each new subdomain?

Comment: Aha, that's a little different then. I would recommend you check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain -- The question is asking pretty much the same thing!

Comment: Close but theirs redirect... I need the subdomain.domain.com to stay intact in the URL bar...