# creating wildcard based subdomain

Tags: virtual, subdomain, wildcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache rewrite based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain)

I am stuck with one problem which not able to solve it. Plz help me to come out of this.

My requirement is: 
I want to have each city name as sub domain in my site. Say www.mysite.com, which can have www.delhi.mysite.com, www.bangalore.mysite.com. The list might go endless. My problem is I don't want to create folders for each of the sub domains. I want to handle it in the URL as query string, say www.mysite.com?city=bangalore. This way I can redirect the request to a single file.

I have made the set up LAMP architecture.

In vhost file, it is

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName *.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

and Also updated .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/index.html [R,L]
```

But still I am getting 404 error.

Is my approach correct?? Can it be achievable??

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: likely duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193651/simple-htaccess-subdomain-rewrite
http://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite/203804#203804

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$           http://www.domain.com/%1/$1 [L,R]
```

plus a rule to not apply this to the `www` prefix.

And next time, please use the *search* function, this has been asked before.

Make sure you have enabled the rewrite module. Try putting the statements into your vhost config instead of `.htaccess`.