# Django - How to get and parse requested URL

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have a blog application. and i want to set all user's accounts under subdomains. Like:

if someone type :

```
userx.blog.com
```

it must redirects to userx's blog page. i need to get that url and parse it from [].blog.com

and render requested user's page.

current profile url:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', view='user_index',
name='user_index'),
```

in browser:

```
blog.com/blog/username
```

i hope i explained it clearly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make something what is called "internal redirect". This will allow you to hide from user that `userx.blog.com` is served actually by `blog.com/blog/userx`.

I also recommend to use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) server as it is superior in every way over Apache :-)

Comment: i just passed to nginx. i want to keep url as userx.blog.com after page rendered. no redirection. is it internal redirect or rewrite rule? which one is correct way for my situation?

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with one of my sites. My solution was to use mod_rewrite in apache to redirect `userx.blog.com` to `blog.com/blog/userx`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

[Apache rewrite based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain)

Hope that helps.