# apache proxypass from subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

I want to proxypass in apache2 from subdomain to other ports like this

http://test1.example.com  ->  http://test1.example.com:6543

Is there anyway to write config file with not specific with this subdomain but all of the subdomain

in anyway like http://.*.example.com  ->  http://.*.example.com:6543

and http://.*.example.com/first/second  ->  http://.*.example.com:6543/first/second

Here is my config that

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName example.com
> ProxyPassMatch ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(.*) http://$1.example.com:6543/$2
> ProxyPassReverse /  http://example.com
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this.  It can proxy with `[P]`.  Use it as follows:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.example.com:6543/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

`%1` is the subdomain, matched in the condition, `$1` is the path, matched by the rule.

---

You can also do this without the `RewriteCond`, using just

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:6543/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

I used the extra step above to make it more informative, e.g. in the event you wanted to [use the subdomain in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49500/519360).